# How to bypass puzzle slide captcha pyhthon selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha, webautomation

I am new to selenium and python in general and want to make an ebay automatisation. I have the problem that i can't bypass a puzzle slider captcha.
The website I am calling is: https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige:gesuche/heimarbeit/k0
Here is a snippet of my code

```
class Ebay(webdriver.Chrome): #verwendeter Browser spielt auch eine Rolle, funktioniert mit Firefox bspw nicht (mehr)
    def __init__(self, teardown=False):
        self.teardown = teardown
        super(Ebay, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.maximize_window()
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
    def get_cookies_values(self, file): #see [1]
        with open(file, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            dict_reader = DictReader(f)
            list_of_dicts = list(dict_reader)
        return list_of_dicts
    def cookies_adding(self): #see [1]
        cookies = get_cookies_values("ebay_cookies.csv")
        for i in cookies:
            self.add_cookie(i)
        self.refresh()
    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.base_url)
    def login(self):
        self.implicitly_wait(15)
        # create wait object which wait for 15s based on the condition
        wait = WebDriverWait(self, 8)
        # Below line will click on the alle akzeptieren button
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click()
        self.implicitly_wait(15)
        # Below line will click on Einloggen button
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Einloggen']"))).click()
        # Below line will send email into text box
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys(const.email)
        self.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(random.randint(2,15))
        #Below line will send password into text box
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "relative inline-flex w-full after:hidden after:hidden")).click
        password_button = self.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "relative inline-flex w-full after:hidden after:hidden")
        time.sleep(random.randint(2,15))
        #Below line will click on Einloggen button
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "u-shadow-border-transition box-border inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-md whitespace-nowrap px-lg text-body-1 font-bold focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:u-ring [&:not(:focus-visible)]:ring-inset min-w-sz-44 h-sz-44 rounded-lg bg-main text-on-main hover:bg-main-hovered enabled:active:bg-main-pressed focus-visible:bg-main-focused w-full")).click
```

I tried saving cookies while beeing logged in in a firefox browser and passing them in the code, I tried a captcha solver which was availiable for free on git and tried to use undetected chrome driver. Nothing works for me. If I trie to solve the captcha manuallay, the next site that opens says  I am blocked, due to suspicious behaviour, I know that I can solve that with a different VPN, but that doesn't solve the problem at it's core, because eventually during testing the code, I will be blocked again and will have to use a different VPN again.
As you can see from the code I am also using maximized window, waituntil conditions and sleep timers in order to make the bot more human like.
Any solutions or tips are very welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `captcha` was invented to stop scripts like yours - so it works correctly :)

Comment: in web scrapping it is natural to use different `IP` (different `VPN` or `proxy server`) in every request. Servers may have complex system to detect scripts and changing `VPN` can be the only solution for some problems. And it may need to use all methods at the same time: `undetected chrome` + changing `VPN` + cookies + random sleep + etc.

Comment: you can try packget: ddddocr